# iOS9 Wrong separator insets in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, xcode7, separator

[image: description]

I want to change my custom uitableviewcell into autolayout under xcode7 with iOS9.
Subviews in cell are well autolayouted.But the separator line always have a huge right insets.
I've tried setLayoutMargins, setSeparatorInset, preservesSuperViewLayoutMargins, cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth. But they didn't work at all. 
Anyone has the same issue?

Thanks.

Update:
My xib file is built since iOS7. Is that too old to configure?

Comment: Isn't Interface builder able to config the inset values ?

Comment: I've tried to set separatorinsets of both tableview and cell with default or explicit. But not work.

Comment: I think u changed  the separator - > custom Insects --> right --> 40 in attribute check once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I didn't change separatorInsets, they are left default. (Left: 15, Right: 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem.
The reason is that I overidded the -(void)layoutSubviews in mycell.m before. 
Comment it, then it works.

Comment: what if i want to add some layout operations

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was looking for this solution for 2 days